# Is there a symbol or name for the space of all Boolean Statements in n variables?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation, terminology, boolean-algebra

I'm working on a problem where I have to describe the equivalence classes of all boolean statements in n variables under the relation P **R** Q <=> P and Q have the same truth table (logically equivalent). Out of curiosity I was wondering if this space (set?) has a name.

Kind of like how $R^n$ is the set of all ordered pairs with n arguments and $P_n$ is the space of all nth degree polynomials. Is there a notation for the space of all Boolean Statements in n variables? Or possibly some kind of analogue to it in set theory or general Boolean Algebra?

Comment: $B_n$?.........

Comment: Thank you, I feel as though i should delete this post, I didn't know the answer would be so obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use $\Bbb B$ for the two-element Boolean algebra and $\Bbb{B}^n$ for your set.